# Weka Random Forest model file size is too big

Tags: serialization, machine-learning, weka, random-forest

I'm using Random Forest in Weka 3.9 GUI. My dataset cotains 211965 instances with 95 attributes. I'm classifing a numerical value.
When I save the model it's size is 1 951 834 KB and it's way too big to load it in my Java application using Weka API.
Am I doing something wrong that causes the file to be that big?

Here is a classifier output from Weka so you can see the paramaters that I have used (I removed attributes list from it to make it shorter).

=== Run information ===

Scheme       weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -P 100 -I 30 -num-slots 0 -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1 -depth 21
Relation     all_cars_wo_cena300k3
Instances    211965
Attributes   95

Test mode    evaluate on training data

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

RandomForest

Bagging with 30 iterations and base learner

weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1 -depth 21 -do-not-check-capabilities

Time taken to build model 15.02 seconds

=== Evaluation on training set ===

Time taken to test model on training data 6.36 seconds

=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.9978
Mean absolute error                   1532.7018
Root mean squared error               3087.1285
Relative absolute error                  5.1246 %
Root relative squared error              6.9288 %
Total Number of Instances           211965